# Limites entre circulos

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas

tengo 2 círculos, uno dibujado en el centro de la pantalla y otro que lo muevo. Lo que quiero hacer es que los círculos no se sobrepongan cuando lo muevo uno sobre otro. Logre hacer algo parecido pero queda horrible, quería saber si hay alguna forma mas eficiente de lograrlo.

Gracias.

```
public class Juego extends SurfaceView implements View.OnTouchListener{

private Paint paint;
int x = 100, y = 100, radio = 100, otroX, otroY;

public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    paint = new Paint();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);

    otroX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
    otroY = canvas.getHeight() / 2;

    canvas.drawCircle(otroX, otroY, radio, paint);

    invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent motionEvent){

    x = (int)motionEvent.getX();
    y = (int)motionEvent.getY();

    double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x - otroX), 2) + Math.pow((y - otroY), 2));

    if (dist <= radio + radio) {

        if (x < otroX) {
            x = otroX - radio - (radio / 2);
        }
        if (x > otroX) {
            x = otroX + radio + (radio / 2);
        }
        if (y < otroY) {
            y = otroY - radio - (radio / 2);
        }
        if (y > otroY) {
            y = otroY + radio + (radio / 2);
        }
    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

}

Esto es lo que tengo: https://mega.nz/#!HZsVhR4L!v6AhTWgJ27U8vV1rYJ_BuO8O2TxgKJV113m58P6ANek

y así es como quisiera que quede: 
https://mega.nz/#!PJFHmDYR!auzX-L-TBTNCZuD8vX8ugUeZmi-HhtWLqs6mUilfW_M

Comment: Agrega una imagen de como queda y otro de como quieres que quede.

Comment: Ya edite mi pregunta con imágenes de lo que tengo y como quiero que me quede.